# Gitignore exclusion for all appearances of a file throughout a directory tree

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory, with many sub-directories, variable depth, always growing. I only want to keep ONE particular file. How do I tell `.gitignore` to ignore all files from these directory and sub directories *except* that one?

Exactly, what I have is a report directory where I daily store many reports. Each new report creates a new sub directory, with a variable name, whith files and sub directories within. I only want to keep the file 'foo'

- REPORTDIRECTORY

  - MONTH_A

    - DAY_HOUR_OF_REPORT

      - file_1
      - file_2
      - foo
      - file_N
      - ANOTHER_DIRECTORY_I_COMPLETELY_IGNORE
    - DAY_HOUR_OF_REPORT

      - file_1
      - file_2
      - foo
      - file_N
      - ANOTHER_DIRECTORY_I_COMPLETELY_IGNORE
  - MONTH_B

    - DAY_HOUR_OF_REPORT

And so on

I have tried many things. Last ones where

```
/REPORTDIRECTORY/**/*
!foo
```

and

```
/REPORTDIRECTORY/**/*
!/REPORTDIRECTORY/**/foo
```

with no success.

I am starting to belive i'm having trouble with double wildcard, because if i put in gitignore:

```
/REPORTDIRECTORY/**/ANOTHER_DIRECTORY_I_COMPLETELY_IGNORE/
```

or

```
REPORTDIRECTORY/**/ANOTHER_DIRECTORY_I_COMPLETELY_IGNORE
```

this 'ANOTHER_DIRECTORY_I_COMPLETELY_IGNORE' is not ignored :(

I'm using Git version `1.8.1.2-preview20130201` for Windows. I'm using `SmartGit` for Windows as GUI (version 4.5), but I suppose the GUI should not be important as `.gitignore` is directly parsed by Git. [Git manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) states double asterisk wildcard should work.

Am I doing something wrong or is it the `.gitignore` parser?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance you need to update to the latest version? According to the [website](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository), `**/` patterns were only supported from 1.8.2 onward.

Answer (score 0):

> Ignoring versioned files
>
> Some files in a repository, which are versioned (*i.e.* they can't be
>   git-ignored), are often changed, but rarely committed. Usually these
>   are various local configuration files that are edited, but should
>   never be committed upstream.
>
> Git lets you ignore those files by assuming they are unchanged. This
>   is done by running the git update-index --assume-unchanged
>   path/to/file.txt command. Once marking a file as such, git will
>   completely ignore any changes on that file; they will not show up when
>   running git status or git diff, nor will they ever be committed.
>
> To make git track the file again, simply run git update-index
>   --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file.txt.

This is directly from the github's [website](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)

Then you can commit the one file as needed, occasionally.  And still ignore generally those changes.

With the addition of a `.gitignore` file in the folder that you are trying to partially ignore, this seems like it would be a reasonable solution.

The content of the `.gitignoe` file in the folder may probably just include the one entry:

```
*/
```

If it is all folders that are to be ignored.